# Use topographical sort with alloy 4.2

Tags: alloy

I'm trying to use topological sort to ﬁnd two different sequential schedules that follow their prereqs. When I execute the code no instances are found and I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
open util/relation

abstract sig Course {
    prereq: set Course, -- c->d in prereq if c is a prerequisite of d
    s1, s2: set Course      -- two sequential course schedules
}
one sig cs1121, cs1122, cs1141, cs2311, cs2321,
                cs3000, cs3141, cs3311, cs3331, cs3411, cs3421, cs3425 extends Course { }

fact {
    no prereq.cs1121
    prereq.cs1122 = cs1121
    prereq.cs1141 = cs1122
    prereq.cs2311 = cs1121
    prereq.cs2321 = cs1122
    prereq.cs3000 = cs3141
    prereq.cs3141 = cs2311
    prereq.cs3141 = cs2321
    prereq.cs3311 = cs2311
    prereq.cs3331 = cs1141
    prereq.cs3331 = cs2311
    prereq.cs3331 = cs2321
    prereq.cs3411 = cs1141
    prereq.cs3411 = cs3421
    prereq.cs3421 = cs1122
    prereq.cs3425 = cs2311 
    prereq.cs3425 = cs2321
}

-- is the given schedule a topological sort of the prereq relation?
pred topoSort [schedule: Course->Course] {
    (all c: Course | lone c.schedule and lone schedule.c) -- no branching in the schedule
    and totalOrder[*schedule, Course] -- and it's a total order
    and prereq in ^schedule -- and it obeys the prerequisite graph
}


pred show {
    s1.irreflexive  and s2.irreflexive  -- no retaking courses!
    s1.topoSort and s2.topoSort -- both schedules are topological sorts of the prereq relation
    s1 != s2    -- the schedules are different
}

run show
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch the solver (under the Options menu) to MiniSAT with Unsat Core, then look at the core. You'll see it highlights

```
 prereq.cs3141 = cs2311
 prereq.cs3141 = cs2321
```

which contradicts your no branching rule.